# AsyncTask doInBackground return empty ArrayList<String> to onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am parsing data from URL in doInBackground and setting values to UI thread in  onPostExecute. So my array ArrayList is global variable:

```
 ArrayList<String> arraylist=new ArrayList<String>();
```

Now, i parse html in doInBackground and add values to global ArrayList , so when i return arraylist to onPostExecute ArrayList() is empty

Here is my code:

```
  ArrayList<String> arraylist=new ArrayList<String>(); // global

  new readtextfile21().execute(rezultat1); 

 public class readtextfile21 extends AsyncTask<String, ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<String>> {

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        Ion.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext())

                .load(rezultat1)

                .asString()

                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {

                        String htmlStringSlike = result.substring(result.indexOf("<!-- BEGIN .shortcode-content -->"), result.length());
                        int startPositionSlika=htmlStringSlike.indexOf("<div class=\"shortcode-content\">");
                        int endPositionSlika=startPositionSlika+"<div class=\"shortcode-content\">".length();

                        while (htmlStringSlike.substring(startPositionSlika, endPositionSlika).indexOf("<!-- END .shortcode-content -->") < 0) {
                            endPositionSlika++;
                        }
                        htmlStringSlike=htmlStringSlike.substring(startPositionSlika,endPositionSlika);

                        while(htmlStringSlike.length()>0){

                            startPositionSlika = htmlStringSlike.indexOf("src=");
                            if(startPositionSlika>0) {

                                String slikaUTekstu=null;
                                startPositionSlika+= "src=".length() + 1;

                                endPositionSlika = startPositionSlika;

                                while (htmlStringSlike.substring(startPositionSlika, endPositionSlika).indexOf(".jpg") < 0 &&  htmlStringSlike.substring(startPositionSlika, endPositionSlika).indexOf(".jpeg") < 0 && htmlStringSlike.substring(startPositionSlika, endPositionSlika).indexOf(".png") < 0) {
                                    endPositionSlika++;
                                }

                                slikaUTekstu = htmlStringSlike.substring(startPositionSlika, endPositionSlika);

                                htmlStringSlike=htmlStringSlike.substring(endPositionSlika);

                                arraylist.add(slikaUTekstu);// when i log values are here
                            }
                            else break;

                        }
                    }

                });

        return arraylist;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {

        System.out.println("u onpost" + result);

        for(int i=0;i<result.size() ;i++){ // result size here is 0???

            slikaTv[i] = (ImageView) v.findViewById(nizSlikaID[i]);

            Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(result.get(i)) // programski slika u dodati layout
                    .into(slikaTv[i]);

            v.findViewById(mLayoutIdArray[i]).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate() {

    }
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Because you are inside the Callback you added to doInBrackground, but you are returning the ArrayList<String> immediately at the end of the method (and it is still empty). To get your code work you need to transform the `Ion.with...` part to a synchronous method. I've checked the library documentation you are using, and you need to use `get()` instead of `setCallback()` to use synchronous request. Read [here](https://github.com/koush/ion#blocking-on-requests)

Comment: @MatPag can you show me how to transofrm Ion.with... please? How to use get() instead of setCallback()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `doInBackground()` method trying with the code below, sorry but i never used this library so i could have made some mistakes.

```
@Override
protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params)
{
    try {
        String result = Ion.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
                .load(params[0])
                .asString()
                .get();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (result != null){
        String htmlStringSlike = result.substring(result.indexOf("<!-- BEGIN .shortcode-content -->"), result.length());
        int startPositionSlika=htmlStringSlike.indexOf("<div class=\"shortcode-content\">");
        int endPositionSlika=startPositionSlika+"<div class=\"shortcode-content\">".length();

        while (htmlStringSlike.substring(startPositionSlika, endPositionSlika).indexOf("<!-- END .shortcode-content -->") < 0) {
            endPositionSlika++;
        }
        htmlStringSlike=htmlStringSlike.substring(startPositionSlika,endPositionSlika);

        while(htmlStringSlike.length()>0){

            startPositionSlika = htmlStringSlike.indexOf("src=");
            if(startPositionSlika>0) {

                String slikaUTekstu=null;
                startPositionSlika+= "src=".length() + 1;

                endPositionSlika = startPositionSlika;

                while (htmlStringSlike.substring(startPositionSlika, endPositionSlika).indexOf(".jpg") < 0 &&  htmlStringSlike.substring(startPositionSlika, endPositionSlika).indexOf(".jpeg") < 0 && htmlStringSlike.substring(startPositionSlika, endPositionSlika).indexOf(".png") < 0) {
                    endPositionSlika++;
                }

                slikaUTekstu = htmlStringSlike.substring(startPositionSlika, endPositionSlika);

                htmlStringSlike=htmlStringSlike.substring(endPositionSlika);

                arraylist.add(slikaUTekstu);// when i log values are here
            } else { 
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return arraylist;
}
```

Comment: @smiljka Glad to hear!!. You can accept the answer if you are satisfied with it ;)

Answer (score 0):

please check the size of arrayList before returning value in doInBackground() method!

Comment: i cheked and before returning is still 0, but i checked when i adding it values is there

Answer (score 0):

Ino provides result asynchronous. That means you need to pause/block current thread until Ino request will be finished.

But it's totally unnecessary to use AsyncTask in this case. You can just move your code from onPostExecute into callback handler.

In case If you want to parse HTML asynchronous (you don't do it right now) you need run asynctask from Ino callback handler.

Comment: Can you explain ho to pause block current UI thread until Ion request finish pls?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is "return arraylist" and you reqeust.

Your request is asynchronous:

Execute step :
First: request

```
Ion.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
            .load(rezultat1)
            .asString()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {...}
```

Second:

```
return arraylist
```

Last step:

```
public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {...}
```

Because request is asynchronous:

```
setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {...}
```

will execute after return;

You can move return code to:

```
while(htmlStringSlike.length()>0){
    ...
}
return arraylist;
```

Hope to help you.